# Bad request 400 when exchanging refresh_token for access_token with box.com

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token

I have successfully done this in the past for other services, however with box.com I get an error and I've tried everything I could think off and that others have suggested here.

I'm using .NET C#;

```
string postdata = "";
postdata += "client_id=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(client_id) + "&";
postdata += "client_secret=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(client_secret) + "&";
postdata += "refresh_token=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(refreshToken) + "&";
postdata += "redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_redirectUri) + "&";
postdata += "grant_type=refresh_token";

var json = PostResponse(new Uri(@"https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token"), postdata);
```

I've tried both with and without urlencoding of the values. Normally urlencoding is not needed in my experience.
I've also tried different order of parameters.

```
private string PostResponse(Uri uri, string postdata)
{
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

    Stream OutputStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    var response = request.GetResponse();
    var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

This code fails with error 400 (bad request). Similar code works fine with for example Google Drive.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong with box.com? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working using box_device_id and box_device_name (indirectly part of my problem) plus examining the response in details which showed that a json error message was returned stating that the refresh token had expired. Turns out that Box expires refresh tokens when using them, issuing a new one. This is different from the other cloud drives I've integrated with.

Comment: The same issue i'm facing. can u please add how you resolved this issue?

Comment: I didn't. Box' policy of expiring refresh tokens made it impossible for me to use their service. I have been in contact with them and hoping they will open up for a less secure scheme like the other cloud solutions use (Dropbox, OneDrive, Google Drive/Cloud Print) where refresh token never expires. I suggest you contact them with the same request so that more than one informs them of the need.